"Circular" motion with a changing radius - is mechanical energy conserved?
Suppose we have a frictionless table with a mass $M$ whirling over it, connected to a taut string which goes through a hole in the middle of the table. The mass $M$ is travelling in a circular motion with a radius $R_0$.
The string is then starting to be pulled inward, so the radius of the "circular" motion in each instant is getting smaller. (I guess the mass $M$ will be travelling in a spiral). The pulling stops when we reach radius $R_1$.

Is mechanical energy conserved during this process? In "regular" circular motion, the radial force provided by the string does no work, as it is perpendicular to the direction of motion.
However, during the time that the string is being pulled, the motion is not circular anymore, but "spiral" (or I guess we could say that it is "circular" in each moment, where at each moment the radius is slightly shorter than in the one before?)
So - it would seem to me that during this time, the radial force by the string actually does work on the object, moving it closer to the centre. It is not obvious to me if this force is still always perpendicular to the velocity of mass $M$.
So - is the force of the string in this scenario always perpendicular to the velocity of $M$? Why or why not?
And consequently, is mechanical energy conserved or not?
Please note that I'm not asking for people to solve a homework problem for me :) I'm interested in understanding the concepts.

This has already been asked many times. The answer is no.

@VincentThacker I thought so. However for some reason the answers in my text book (An Introduction To Mechanics by Kleppner and Kolenkow) seem to suggest otherwise. They say that mechanical energy is conserved (as there's no friction). Are they simply wrong?

Angular momentum is conserved; kinetic energy is not.

You do work pulling down the string, so the energy of the circling block is not conserved. If you let the pulling be done by a falling mass the sum of the energies is conserved.
